# Функция int main(void) уже имеет текст реализации. Код ошибки

Tags: c++

Делаю одну программу для эксперимента и возникла одна ошибка.
Сделал новый проект и оставил ту же функцию и те же свойства, а ошибка так и осталась, в чем может быть дело?
**Ошибка:** функция "int main(void)" уже имеет текст реализации (**C2084**)

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "func.h"

using namespace std;

void Interface();

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    Interface();
}
```

**func.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Source.cpp"

void Interface() {
    int quest;
    while (true) {
        cout << "1. Открыть базу" << endl;
        cout << "2. Закрыть программу" << endl;
        cout << "Номер пути _\b";
        cin >> quest;
        if (quest = 1) {
            cout << "Открыто!";
        }
        else if (quest = 2) {
            cout << "Закрыто!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы `.cpp` файл подключаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверное понимание, что должно находиться в заголовочном файле, а что - в `.cpp`.

В заголовочном файле располагайте *объявления*, а *определения* - в cpp-файле. В заголовочном файле располагаются также inline-реализации, шаблоны и т.п. вещи, но в вашем случае все, что следует разместить в `func.h` - это

```
void Interface();
```

Все остальное - в `.cpp`-файлах, и не включать `.cpp`-файлы с помощью директивы `#include` - иначе вы получаете нарушение *правила одного определения*.

Comment: "В заголовочном файле располагайте объявления, а определения - в cpp-файле." - а как же, например, определения классов в заголовках? Я считаю неправильным подход "запомни что должно быть в .h, а что в .cpp"

Comment: @Croessmah Думаю, без определенного упрощения давать сразу стандарт и длинные определения - неверно дидактически. Можно изучать электричество и магнетизм, начиная с уравнений Максвелла, но обычно сначала рассказывают об эбонитовой палочке и шерстяных штанишках :)

Comment: Вообще-то здесь скорее неверное понимание работы препроцессора. Конкретно того, что директива `#include` заменяется им на содержимое указанного файла. А советы что где размещать прямо вводят в заблуждение.

Comment: @VTT Простите, просто уже достала неконструктивная критика. Вы считаете, что ответ неверный? Нет вопросов, давайте свой. А то получается, как в той поговорке - "не знаю, как, но знаю, что не так". Как вы понимаете, я (как и вы) могу написать программу, нарушающую мои же советы, и которая будет компилироваться. Стоит ли приводить ее как образец, как нужно писать программы? Вы не находите, что если человек задает *такой* вопрос, то его сначала нужно научить пусть более строгим, но более безопасным правилам работы? А потом, когда он разберется, что к чему - он и сам поймет, что к чему.